# jQuery How to select the first instance of an image class that is not hidden

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Notice that for the given table below, the first row or the first many rows may have the 'imgProgress' hidden.

Without knowing the id of the first row that does not have the image hidden, I need to be able to select only the first instance of 'imgProgress' and hide it.

There will be many more rows in the application table

I have tried:
$('.schedule-table .imgProgress:first').fadeOut('slow')
 and 
$('.imgProgress:first').fadeOut('slow')
but no luck yet

Here is a sample: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Zp2S4/

```
<table id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_Table_Name" class="schedule-table" cellspacing="1" border="0" style="width:100%;"> 
<tr>     
<td class="resource-header"><span class="resource-header-text">Personnel</span></td>     
<td class="resource-header"><span class="resource-header-text">Office</span></td>     
<td class="dow"><span class="dow">Tue<br>01</span></td>
<td class="dow"><span class="dow">Wed<br>02</span></td>
<td class="dow"><span class="dow">Thu<br>03</span></td>
<td class="dow"><span class="dow">Fri<br>04</span></td>
<td class="weekend"><span class="weekend-text">Sat<br>05</span></td>
<td class="weekend"><span class="weekend-text">Sun<br>06</span></td>
<td class="dow"><span class="dow">Mon<br>07</span></td>
    <td class="dow"><span class="dow">Thu<br>31</span></td> 
</tr> 

    <tr class="DataRow" id="DataRow_3"> 
<td class="resource" style="display:none;"><span class="resource">3</span></td> 
<td class="resource" id="TD_Name">
    <div style="float:left;">Lname, Fname</div>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <img id="imgProgress" style="display:none;"  src="http://i193.photobucket.com/albums/z137/Pixel_Pete/microUS.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Working..." />
    </div>        
</td> 
<td class="resource" id="TD_Office"><span>A6OK</span></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_1" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=01-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_2" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=02-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_3" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=03-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_4" onDblClick="location.href('.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=04-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="weekend" id="TD_5" onDblClick="location.href('.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=05-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="weekend" id="TD_6" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=06-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td>  
    </tr>

<tr class="DataRow" id="DataRow_15"> 
<td class="resource" style="display:none;"><span class="resource">15</span></td> 
<td class="resource" id="TD_Name">
    <div style="float:left;">Lname, Fname</div>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <img id="imgProgress" style="display:none;"  src="http://i193.photobucket.com/albums/z137/Pixel_Pete/microUS.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Working..." />
    </div>        
</td> 
<td class="resource" id="TD_Office"><span>A6OK</span></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_1" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=01-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_2" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=02-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_3" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=03-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_4" onDblClick="location.href('.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=04-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="weekend" id="TD_5" onDblClick="location.href('.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=05-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="weekend" id="TD_6" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=06-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td>  
    </tr>    

<tr class="DataRow" id="DataRow_8"> 
<td class="resource" style="display:none;"><span class="resource">8</span></td> 
<td class="resource" id="TD_Name">
    <div style="float:left;">Lname, Fname</div>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <img src="http://i193.photobucket.com/albums/z137/Pixel_Pete/microUS.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Working..." id="imgProgress" />
    </div>        
</td> 
<td class="resource" id="TD_Office"><span>A6OK</span></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_1" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=01-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_2" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=02-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_3" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=03-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_4" onDblClick="location.href('.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=04-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="weekend" id="TD_5" onDblClick="location.href('.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=05-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="weekend" id="TD_6" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=06-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td>  
    </tr>

<tr class="DataRow" id="DataRow_5"> 
<td class="resource" style="display:none;"><span class="resource">5</span></td> 
<td class="resource" id="TD_Name">
    <div style="float:left;">Lname, Fname</div>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <img src="http://i193.photobucket.com/albums/z137/Pixel_Pete/microUS.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Working..." id="imgProgress" />
    </div>        
</td> 
<td class="resource" id="TD_Office"><span>A6OK</span></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_1" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=01-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_2" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=02-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_3" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=03-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_4" onDblClick="location.href('.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=04-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="weekend" id="TD_5" onDblClick="location.href('.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=05-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="weekend" id="TD_6" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=06-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td>  
    </tr>
<tr>     
<tr class="DataRow" id="DataRow_11"> 
<td class="resource" style="display:none;"><span class="resource">11</span></td> 
<td class="resource" id="TD_Name">
    <div style="float:left;">Lname, Fname</div>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <img src="http://i193.photobucket.com/albums/z137/Pixel_Pete/microUS.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Working..." id="imgProgress" />
    </div>        
</td> 
<td class="resource" id="TD_Office"><span>A6OK</span></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_1" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=01-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_2" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=02-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_3" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=03-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="dow" id="TD_4" onDblClick="location.href('.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=04-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="weekend" id="TD_5" onDblClick="location.href('.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=05-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td> 
<td class="weekend" id="TD_6" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=06-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td>  
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle demo is set to use MooTools, not jQuery.

Comment: Your images should each have a unique ID... not that it will effect the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that:

```
$('.schedule-table .imgProgress:visible:first').fadeOut('slow');
```

should be what you're looking for?

---

**Edited** to address some of the faults in the mark-up, that prevented the above from working:

Problems:

1. Multiple elements with the same `id` (an `id` **must** be **unique** within the document).
2. The code posted was selecting elements of `class` 'imgProgress', which returned no results since the only attribute containing 'imgProgress' was the `id`.

   ```
   $('img:visible:first').each(
       function(){
           $(this).addClass(this.id); // takes the images id, and adds it as a class
           $(this).removeAttr('id'); // removes the id attribute.
       });

   $('img.imgProgress:visible:first').fadeOut(1000);
   ```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Zp2S4/7/)

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).
- [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with the jsfiddle link given (after changing it to use jQuery).

Comment: @Blair, thanks, I hadn't looked at the morass of html properly. Since rectified and now, following the edit, works. :)

Answer (score 3):

Get the first image that is not hidden,

```
$("img:not(:hidden))").eq(0);
```

Comment: @Bengal: but are you still trying to use the MooTools library with a jQuery code?

Comment: Updated with an example at http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/Zp2S4/8/. Make sure you understand what `:hidden` does. Don't use duplicate id's, and of course, use the correct framework :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your markup.

For one, multiple elements are using the id `#imgProgress`. Id's in HTML **must** be unique. You cannot have two elements with the same id. You might want to change that to the class `.imgProgress`.

Once that is fixed, using the [`:visible` pseudo-selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) will enable you to hide the first visible image:

```
$('.schedule-table .imgProgress:visible:first').fadeOut('slow');
```

Also note that your jsFiddle demo is using [MooTools](http://mootools.net), not [jQuery](http://jquery.com). You must make sure to select the proper JavaScript library from the left toolbar when creating a jsFiddle demo.

[Here is a working version of the jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BkpBJ/) with the changes above implemented.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it your selector is all wrong and you have semantic errors in your html.

You have multiple images with the id imgProgress which will not validate.

Your selector is looking for tags with the class imgProgress.

You should update your html to remove the multiple id and use classes instead your selector should work then.